# How to programmatically set RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT to FALSE?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I change pragmatically layout property, `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to `android:layout_alignParentRight="false"`. I know how to make that `true` from the code, using this:

```
LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)btn.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

How can I make this `false` on some condition from java code?

Comment: I would set it to what you want, example ALIGN_LEFT if that is what you seeking.

Comment: Its simple. change RelativeLayout.TRUE to RelativeLayout.FALSE

Comment: @SankarV there is no thing like `RelativeLayout.FALSE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one.

`params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,0)`

This will set false to the property alignParrentRight = false

Comment: What would be the equivalent to true? 1 doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

just add like this no need to add False or true, try like this

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

Comment: will that make `layout_alignParentRight` property false?

Comment: What do you want? you want to set that view as align parent right ? or else.

Comment: In the layout the `layout_alignParentRight` is set to true, only for some condition I want to change the that to false

Comment: If you want to use that set that rule to params , otherwise don't use that property.